# Grails - run-app error

Tags: grails

I have installed Grails on CentOS. I created the app which worked.

But when I run `run-app`, I get the following error. I have not made any changes yet, just created app.

```
grails run-app -Dserver.port=8090

Error Error packaging application: Error loading Config.groovy: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.ju() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), dump(), get(java.lang.Object), put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), max(groovy.lang.Closure) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Running with stacktrace gives

at _GrailsPackage$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage.groovy:48)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
```

Comment: What version of grails and java you are using?

Comment: also `grep ju grails-app/conf/*.groovy` in case you have already done some changes; putting a `ju()` in e.g. `Config.groovy` would result in the same error.

Comment: [centos64 ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
[centos64 ~]$ grails -version
Grails version: 2.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Mistake on my part - when I was editing Config.groovy to change the port, I accidently changed the line

grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true by putting a space in "jul".

Many thanks cfrick